# Variable Scope - JAVA Class/Method

Tags: java, arraylist, scope

I am reading in data from a text file into an ArrayList and then trying to search for a particular string in that ArrayList (the second method).

I believe that I am correctly reading in the data however am struggling to write methods to implement on the ArrayList once it has been filled. For instance, in the checking method below, it is returning a false when I am certain the input String is in the data structure.

I recognize this is likely a problem with my variable scope or how my methods are interacting with each other (i.e, the arraylist is not actually filled with the data when I am checking it).

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class Word {


ArrayList<String> diclist = new ArrayList<String>();

private void readIn() throws FileNotFoundException {

   File file = new File("filepath");
   Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
   s.useDelimiter("\n");

   while (s.hasNextLine()) {
       diclist.add(s.nextLine());
    }
   s.close();
                                                    }

public boolean checkIn(String z) {//Check if input string z is in diclist

    for (int i = 0; i < diclist.size(); i++) {
        if (diclist.get(i).equals(z)) {return true;}
    }
    return false;
                                                    }
}
```

Comment: `"I recognize this is likely a problem with my variable scope or how my methods are interacting with each other..."` -- Well, how *are* you calling this code?  What's in `filepath`? What are you passing as an argument to `checkIn()`?

Comment: Try printing the contents of your ArrayList, and the value of z in your check method. you'll then be able to see whether the contents really are as you expect.

Comment: Please post your file content (or only a snippet if it is too large) and the String you're looking for. Mind that your `equals` check is _case sensitive_. Btw: you're working correctly with `diclist` in this code, so it doesn't look like a problem with the variable scope.

Comment: My hunch is that you're never calling `readIn()`.  You don't call in from inside the `Word` class that you've posted, and since it's `private`, you *can't* call it from anywhere else.  Calling `checkIn()` on an empty `ArrayList` will always return `false`.

Comment: Azurefrog you are totally correct. I was not calling the readIn method to initialize the array. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no obvious problems in the code you posted so far. After calling `readIn`, if the file exists, readable and not empty, the list should get populated. I suggest running it through a debugger.

Note that the `checkIn` method can be vastly simplified to this:

```
return diclist.contains(z);
```